# Can I use Shiny R to scale a full blown webapp?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have built a web app, that allows you to build a theoretical portfolio tailored to your needs. My question is, if I want to make this available to thousands of people what is the best way of doing it? Should I do this as an R markdown and use flexdashboard with shiny or do i need to get a shiny pro licence?? Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at this video by rstudio on scaling https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/scaling-shiny/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we scale applications today is through the use of containers and their orchestrators (e.g. Kubernetes). You simply place your application inside a container and then replicate those containers out as many times as you need, as a cluster. So a single instance of your application never has that many concurrent users. Since your app is data-driven you may have some challenges around persisting models/data across all containers, but there are approaches to dealing with this. Look into microservices to get a feel for the approach I’ve just described.